# no me marca los errores de compilacion a partir de ejecutar una consulta a sqlite

Tags: android, android-studio, sqlite

estoy experimentando un error extraño. Y es que a partir de que pongo esta linea de codigo: `db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE if not exists pastillas (_id Integer primary key autoincrement,nombre String,frecuencia String)");` no me detecta los errores de compilacion. Puedo poner lo que quiera, por ejemplo `tocino=velocidad` y no me lo marca en rojo. Si comento la linea del create table me marca el error en rojo pero si no la comento no. Este es el codigo del mainactivity que es donde se produce la incidencia.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    //Contador counter;

    //public static MainActivity Instance;
    private static TextView texto;
    private Button visualizar;
    private final static String CHANNEL_ID="NOTIFICACION";
    private final static int NOTIFICACION_ID=0;
    private SimpleDateFormat dateFormat;
    private String date;
    private ImageView anadir;
    private static final String TAG ="MainActivity";
    private dbHelper dbhelper;
    public static SQLiteDatabase db;
    int hour,minute;
    Spinner pastilla;
    String[] pastillas;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        visualizar=findViewById(R.id.visualizar);
        anadir=findViewById(R.id.anadir);
        pastilla=findViewById(R.id.pastilla);
        dbhelper= new dbHelper(MainActivity.this);
        db= dbhelper.getWritableDatabase();
        if (db!=null)
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Base de datos creada", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        else
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error al crear base de datos", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE if not exists pastillas (_id Integer primary key autoincrement,nombre String,frecuencia String)");
        Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM pastillas", null);
        tocino=velocidad;
        if (c != null) {
            c.moveToFirst();
            int i=0;
            do {
                //String user = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("user"));
                pastillas[i]=c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("nombre"));
                i++;
            } while (c.moveToNext());
        }
        anadir.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Anadir.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

    }

}
```

y este es el codigo del dbhelper:

```
public class dbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static final int DATABASE_VERSION=1;
    public static final String DATABASE_NOMBRE="medicacion.db";
    public static final String TABLE_DATOS="datos";
    private Context contexto;

    public dbHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NOMBRE, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        contexto=context;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        //db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE sistemas (Nombre String,version Real)");

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        //db.execSQL("drop table "+TABLE_DATOS);
        //onCreate(db);
    }
}
```

Comment: Te refieres a que "velocidad" es una variable que no existe y debería marcarla en rojo?

Comment: exactamente, no me lo marca en rojo.

Comment: Asegura que no tengas activado "Power Save Mode", revisa mi respuesta

Answer (score 0):

Si no te muestra los errores Android Studio, debes verificar que el "modo ahorro de energía" no este activado, debes tenerlo desactivado como se muestra en la siguiente imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]